# Big SPARQL queries fails in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, tuples, sparql, semantic-web, jena

Is there any limit of maximum number of "OPTIONAL" parameters in oracle spatial jena?

The reason why I am asking is, I have a big query sized around 5000 letters which executes perfect. I am using oracle 11.2.0.3 db with semantic web features.

But if I add one more OPTIONAL field in the query, it fails.

Giving this Exception below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.OracleRepeatApply.nextStage(OracleRepeatApply.java:794)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterRepeatApply.makeNextStage(QueryIterRepeatApply.java:101)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterRepeatApply.hasNextBinding(QueryIterRepeatApply.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterProcessBinding.hasNextBinding(QueryIterProcessBinding.java:49)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterConvert.hasNextBinding(QueryIterConvert.java:54)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterConvert.hasNextBinding(QueryIterConvert.java:54)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterDistinctReduced.hasNextBinding(QueryIterDistinctReduced.java:42)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:30)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:30)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream.hasNext(ResultSetStream.java:57)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.ResultSetMem.<init>(ResultSetMem.java:82)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.TextOutput.write(TextOutput.java:133)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.TextOutput.write(TextOutput.java:116)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.TextOutput.write(TextOutput.java:104)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.TextOutput.format(TextOutput.java:51)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter.out(ResultSetFormatter.java:109)
```

I am sure the query is correct (this query worked in Stardog Tuple store). any idea why this happens? Is there any restriction/configuration for query length in oracle?

EDITS:-
  The query is similar to below

```
"PREFIX............"
+"SELECT........"
+"WHERE {......"
+"..............."
//+"OPTIONAL {  ?store have:stored ?milk }"                     
//+"OPTIONAL {  ?store have:balance ?bal }"
+"}"
```

when I uncomment  any '**one**' of the OPTIONAL line the query works.
If  I uncomment both of the OPTIONAL lines query fails.

Comment: There's no Jena imposed limitation.  However, the stacktrace does not look a simple length-of-query issue but to do with the structure of the query.  You may be able to reduce the query to something smaller you could post here.  (Obviously access to the source of OracleRepeatApply would help.)

Comment: please see the edited question.. can you give the details about "OracleRepeatApply "

Comment: You might consider sticking with a real RDF database, as evaluating SPARQL is what they're all *designed* to do.

Comment: +1 To @Michael's comment, you actually said the query works in Stardog which is a native RDF database (and IMHO the best one available on the market) so why do you need to use Oracle?

Comment: My client needs a branded one. oracle is pure pain in a**

Comment: Then you should talk with your client before you deliver something you know is brittle.  What's in their best interests and what they think are in their best interests are not always the same thing.

Comment: anybody have any idea about "OracleRepeatApply" ?